# What is the analog of the CNOT gate in an arbitrary basis?

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a pair of two-level systems. The Hilbert space basis is given by
$$
\beta = \{|a_i\rangle|b_j\rangle\}_{i,j=0}^1.
$$
So, an arbitrary state $|\psi\rangle$ can be expressed as
$$
|\psi\rangle = c_{00}|a_0\rangle|b_0\rangle + c_{01}|a_0\rangle|b_1\rangle + c_{10}|a_1\rangle|b_0\rangle + c_{11}|a_1\rangle|b_1\rangle.
$$

Is it true that the CNOT gate would just be an analog of the binary CNOT:
$$
CNOT = |a_0\rangle|b_0\rangle \langle a_0|\langle b_0| + |a_0\rangle|b_1\rangle \langle a_0|\langle b_1| + |a_1\rangle|b_1\rangle \langle a_1|\langle b_0| + |a_1\rangle|b_0\rangle \langle a_1|\langle b_1|?
$$
Are there any other possible representations of CNOT in the basis $\beta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a natural representation of CNOT: If $U$ represents a change of basis from $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ to $\{|a_0\rangle, |a_1\rangle\}$ and $V$ represents a change of basis from $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ to $\{|b_0\rangle, |b_1\rangle\}$, then
$$
CNOT := |0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle1| \otimes X \tag{1}
$$
is defined on the joint system $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$, and so rotating this operator into the new basis gives
\begin{align}
(U \otimes V) CNOT (U^\dagger \otimes V^\dagger) &= |a_0\rangle\langle a_0| \otimes I + |a_1\rangle \langle a_1| \otimes V(|0\rangle \langle 1| + |1\rangle \langle 0|) V^\dagger \tag{2}
\\&= |a_0\rangle\langle a_0| \otimes I + |a_1\rangle \langle a_1| \otimes  \tag{3}(|b_0\rangle \langle b_1| + |b_1\rangle \langle b_0|) 
\end{align}
which recovers the analog you suggest. This may no longer make sense if you choose to work in an entangled basis.

Answer (score 3):

The CNOT gate is equal to $I - 2|v\rangle\langle v|$ where $|v\rangle = |1\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$.

The simplest way to generalize CNOT is to vary $v$. For example, the CZ gate is what you get from $|v\rangle = |1\rangle\otimes|1\rangle$.